selenium can't spawn chrome even if latest version and all required options. Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally
I have been running chromedriver inside a debian VPS with the following code for some years:
CHROME_WEBDRIVER_PATH=''

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-setuid-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-using")
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(CHROME_WEBDRIVER_PATH), options=options)

I always download the latest version of google-chrome and chromedriver. Since version 128 the last line hangs for several minutes before returning the following exception:
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /opt/google/chrome/chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)

I have tried commenting out some options, changing their order etc, but nothing has worked so far.
$ ./chromedriver --version
ChromeDriver 129.0.6668.89 (951c0b97221f8d4ba37cf97d324505c832251cf9-refs/branch-heads/6668@{#1503})
$ google-chrome --version 
Google Chrome 129.0.6668.89 


this happens from version 128
